# Android intent in Facebook Browser not working anymore

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, browser, chromium

Android 5.0.1
LG Nexus 5

Hi,

we have a link http://dl.zeek.me/fb.html where we are redirecting users directly into the app if they have it, or to the play store if they don't have it.

I found that the intent redirect is not working on Facebook browser, if user don't have the app.
I inserted the App Links, as your documentation is suggesting.
I also checked you are using the chromium user agent, and the link is working perfectly in Chrome for Android (last version, 40+)

Here is my intent url:
 url = 'intent://t4Zeek/#Intent;scheme=oauth;package=com.marketplaceapp;end';

Here are my app links:

meta property="al:android:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marketplaceapp&hl=en"

meta property="al:android:package" content="com.marketplaceapp"

meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Zeek"

I attached the errors I get on FB native app.

Thanks,

Simon 
Last known working date:
January 19, 2015
Related Apps
Zeek

Comment: If you have App Links working Why do you need intent url?

Comment: @Muthu Hi, I have App Links in the file, but they're not working. They don't take nor an intent, or a normal URL, in al:android:url meta

I've also set the package and app name, as suggested on Facebook Docs.

Comment: <meta property="al:android:url" content="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marketplaceapp&hl=en">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.marketplaceapp">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Zeek">

Comment: did you set scheme in your app? Because I find in complete metatags.

Comment: Let me add an working Applinks as an answer check them.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Also, your al:android:url is incorrect. It should point to a scheme that your app handles, not the play store url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are my working Applink specification. This may help you.

```
 <meta property="al:android:url" content="appname://xxx/347" />
 <meta property="al:android:package" content="android package name" />
 <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="app name" />
 <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="some title" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="url link" />
```

and You can check them using  [Facebook tools](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

Comment: I'm checking now. Thanks for your help. I'll keep you up!